# Anagram Array stuck

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

As the title suggests I'm curious to find a working algorithm for the anagram dilemma. I have an algorithm worked out but I'm stuck when it comes to implementing it.

This is where I get stuck.
Loop until user enters new space and keep on reading a character.

I have an array that's holding 26 slots all set to 0 [1 meaning that certain char was spotted]. I'm stuck when it comes to taking that certain character (Example D) and putting it into the 4th slot of the array. Do i do a bunch of if statements, switch? Just seems like I'm over complicating it.

I don't want code! Just help with that certain segment of the algorithm.
Also please keep in mind I've only just finished learning about arrays then assigned this project (following a textbook) so I haven't learned anything about strings just yet, so keep it basic.

Thank you!

Comment: `array[tolower(curr_input_char)-'a']++;` ?

Comment: So you're taking the array, lowercasing it and subtracting the ascii value and the difference gives you the slot that it should be on in the array? I never would've thought of this.. Ty so much! Could i ask why you post incremented though? is it because arrays start at 0?

Comment: Perform `isalpha(curr_input_char)` check in advance if necessary. The number of characters is required when comparing Anagram. E.g `"Dad"` => `array[3 /* 'd' - 'a' */]` == 2 and `array[0]` == 1.